# ASP.NET SqlParameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, sqlclient

the SqlParameter I believe is my issue and I'm not sure a way around it. I have a check box list to store multiple values, such as "[ID],[City],[Amount]" and when add them into my listcheckbox string, I can see it's there but when I pass it into a SqlParameter, it's only grabbing "[ID]" one name from the list and not the rest.

```
SqlParameter TableList = new SqlParameter("@TableList", listCheckBox);
```

Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: See the duplicate for how to work with parameters. A parameters can hold **1** value, no more.

Comment: From the code shown I can only guess that you are trying to pass the whole ListCheckbox control as the parameter value - this will never work because an SqlParameter can only handle primitve types like strings or numbers.

Comment: @Filburt that is not accurate. An SQLParameter can also hold a data table, corresponding to a user defined table type in the database.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Admittedly I over-simplyfied here but since the OP is clearly a beginner I thought it best to leave the complex types unmentioned.